# How can I open a .pkg file manually?

Tags: mac, applications, security, install, pkg

Some applications come in .pkg files, and ask for you administrator password, even if all they do is copy the binary to /Applications.

I like to have my applications in ~/Applications, and I do not like to give administrative permissions to anything that is not from the mothership.

Is there a way that I can manually open the .pkg file and pull out the application? There is PackageMaker in the Developer Tools, but that does not seem to do it (it did produce some output that makes me think that there really are no scripts or other pieces in the installer, just the application).

Comment: Try [unpkg](http://www.timdoug.com/unpkg/).

Answer (score 86):

If you right click it, and click **Show Package Contents** you'll get a few files in a Contents folder. (Note: if you do not see **Show Package Contents** you will need to open Terminal.app and run `pkgutil --expand mystubbornpackage.pkg path/to/expand`)

One is a BOM file (bill of materials) which gets turned into a receipt that you can use to uninstall the app.  This file contains a manifest of everything the package will install and where to; to read this file, use the [**lsbom**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsbom.8.html) command.

Most packages (I'm using Office 2008 here) also have an Archive.pax.gz file, this contains everything that Installer will move into the various folders as instructed in the BOM file.  Most apps seem to have the .app in this archive, although dragging that to /Applications might leave it without frameworks it needs to run; so you'll have to figure out which other files it needs and where it needs them to get it to work.

Additionally, all packages can log messages, if you hit **Cmd-L** (or choose the **Installer Log** option from the **Window** menu, you can view them as they're generated.  This might give you an idea what extra things it's installing, at the very least it's some more information if you're untrusting of the package.

Comment: I don't get "Show Package Contents" in the right-click menu.

Comment: @Thilo If you aren't getting the option to "Show Package Contents" then the pkg file was created as flat file. Apple introduced flat-style pkg's a couple years ago

Comment: @username: So how do I open those?

Comment: [`pkgutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgutil.1.html) will do that. 

You can expand it using `pkgutil --expand file.pkg path_to_expand` and it'll convert it into a directory style package.

Comment: @username, What does "flat" even mean?

Comment: @MathewHall, Does pkgutil, unpkg, SuspiciousPackage, and Pacifist all show the same output?

Comment: Confusingly, often times "flat" pkg files seem to contain "non flat" pkg files.

Comment: Note: use `--expand-full` to extract "Payload" file if you have it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166805/how-to-extract-contents-from-payload-file-in-a-apple-macos-update-package

Answer (score 36):

In addition to what Matthew Hall said, you can also hit Cmd-I in the Installer app to see what files the installer will install and where.

Comment: +1. With this I could quickly verify that there is just the application binary in there, no other system-wide stuff.

Answer (score 8):

`pkgutil --expand` was failing for me with the following error:

`Error encountered while creating .. Error 17: File exists`

But I managed to extract the files with `xar` instead:

`xar -xvf foo.pkg`

Comment: this works for me.  but apparently, if you give pkgutil a non-existence directory as destination that makes the 17 error go away.

Comment: Where does it extract it to though?

Comment: Current dir. @CodyBugstein

Answer (score 7):

If you don't trust the installer enough to give administrative permissions to install, then why do you trust the binary in /Applications?

[Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) will let you look in package files. This doesn't necessarily just let you "pull out the binary".

Comment: I do not trust the binary, either. I want to never ever give it administrative permissions (which it should not need anyway).

Comment: As long as you don't run the app from any user that has admin privileges, your trust will be upheld. Don't forget that even a user level app can make requests from admin level processes so it's a lot of work to run apps you don't actually trust.

Comment: @ghoppe, It's because defaults sometimes arent optimized for the users but the app creators. Eg instead of installing all the installation junk that comes by default, I can select to take only the files that are of essence. Eg when downloading Mysql / Java / etc.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can try,

```
sudo installer -pkg ~/Downloads/packagename.pkg -target ~/Applications/
```

OR

```
installer -pkg ~/Downloads/packagename.pkg -target ~/Applications/
```

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. It still insisted to "Installing at base path /" and then asked for the admin password.

Comment: It's possible to install to a disk image created with something like `hdiutil create -size 200m -fs HFS+ -volname Scratch scratch.dmg` and then copy the files to the locations you prefer. You still need the sudo to run the installer unfortunately.

Comment: I get error `installer: Error - This version of OS X 10.11 cannot be installed on this computer.`

Answer (score 2):

1. After you succeed in opening the package, look for the Archive.pax.gz file that was mentioned earlier.
2. Create a new empty folder on your desktop naming it whatever you wish. I usually name them "xxxx" or "zzzz" etc. to make typing easier later.
3. Option-drag a copy of the Archive.pax.gz file into that new folder "xxxx" on your desktop.

   If the file is inside of read-only media you can just drag it to your "xxxx" folder without the Option key to create a copy.
4. Now open Terminal.app and at the command line navigate to your new "xxxx" directory and list the directory's contents to confirm that your Archive.pax.gz file is there:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/xxxx
   ls -al
   ```
5. Now there are two simple commands to enter:

   ```
   gunzip -v Archive.pax.gz
   ```

   Gzip will tell you that it has replaced "Archive.pax.gz" with "Archive.pax") Now list the directory's contents again to confirm this.

   ```
   pax -r -f Archive.pax
   ```

   (You must separate `-r` and `-f`, as `-rf` will not work)
6. Finally, list the directory's contents again with `ls -al`. In addition to your Archive.pax file you will now see a directory hierarchy probably containing one or more directories.

   The files in that directory hierarchy will illustrate to you where the OS X installer would install files on your system as if your "xxxx" directory was the root directory "/".
7. You may then manually copy those files to their destinations if you wish.

Comment: In other words `cd ~/Desktop; cp Package.pkg/Contents/Archive.pax.gz .; gunzip -v Archive.pax.gz; pax -r -f Archive.pax`.  You don't need to describe everything at *that* level of detail.

Comment: Lri, I gave that amount of detail so users at any level of expertise would be able to follow it and be successful. Granted, your cryptic version would achieve the same results. However, other users reading this in the future who may not be familiar with the command line might be hopelessly lost.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for inspecting package files is [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/). It also allows you to copy files out of the package.

Not only will it provide all the information you need in the app it also install a Quick Look plug in so just selecting the package file and hitting the space bar opens up a window with the most essential information.

Answer (score 1):

[UnArchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver) did the trick.

Install UnArchiver, open UnArchiver; while it is open - double click on that pesky `MAMP_MAMP_3.5.pkg`

Follow the steps to install MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The [Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver) can do this; it will do the same as `pkgutil --expand` but using drag-and-drop. It's a better replacement for Apple's Archive Utility.app anyways.